# Remote execution in Workgroup network

Tags: workgroup, remote-access

Consider this scenario:

```
Please don't say that it would be better if I created a Domain network;
Just consider this scenario.
```

10 PCs are all interconnected via a switch to a workgroup network named WORKGROUP;

PCs specs(all are the same): Windows XP SP2 en (build:2600.xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)

I have full physical control over my own PC (one of those 10 PCs) and what I know about the other ones:

**IPs of all 10 PCs.**

**Administrator account name of all 10 PCs.**

**Administrator account password of all 10 PCs.**

How can I execute an application on the other PCs???(without touching them)

How can modify their registry settings???(without touching them)

Answer (score 1):

PSExec from Sysinternals for remotely executing commands.

Not being on a domain will make it a bit of a pain, but you can use it to manually execute commands on a remote machine with an administrative username and password.

Editing the registry can be done via `regedit`, simply by going to the `File` menu and selecting `Connect Network Registry`.  This needs the `Remote Registry` service enabled on the remote machine.

Again... a pain without a domain, but as long as you know the administrative credentials of the remote system, it can be done.

Comment: **remember: without touching them and completely remote**.using PSExec is not possible in my case because it needs to enable Hidden Admin Share on the PCs and also port 445 must be open on them. And about remote registry, I tried to use that but although the Remote Registry Service is running on the PCs and I can find them in the **Select Computer** window of regedit, it says: **Unable to connect to the remote machine, Make sure you have permission to administer this computer**. Any idea?

Comment: Yup, you're screwed.  If the machines aren't setup to allow remote access, you'll need to physically touch them to change that before you can get remote access.  Try RDP/`mstsc.exe` as a hail-mary, but odds are that's not set up either.  Someone's gonna have to touch them to make them remotely accessible.

Comment: It's ridiculous that I have Administrator credentials of all PCs but can do nothing remotely!!! Please help

Comment: There's no help to be had, windows is not set up like that. Possibly logmein or RDP or other remote desktop software, though that would require the users allowing you access at the time. Alternatively, if the only reason you can't deploy a domain is a lack of funds, then perhaps take a look at http://www.turnkeylinux.org/domain-controller. It's a free linux-based domain controller. I am NOT recommending it though, just providing options.

Comment: And to be fair to Windows, other operating systems aren't either.  You can't access a Linux host or an Apple host remotely unless you make the necessary pre-configurations. The firewall doesn't care if you have the password for `root`, nor does SELinux, etc.